# how to say that given dateTime is already in UTC time format

Tags: javascript, datetime, utc, datetime-format

Here is a ***UTC*** dateTime string as

```
Jan 7, 2014 10:37:42 AM  //parsed UTC date time
```

When I parsed this *string to `date`* like

```
var date = new Date("Jan 7, 2014 10:37:42 AM")
```

This returns the dateTime in local format like

```
Tue Jan 07 2014 05:07:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How can I say that this date is already in UTC?

Here are my tries:
1. Appending UTC to dateTime as

```
var now = new Date('Jan 7, 2014 10:37:42 AM UTC');
//returns Tue Jan 07 2014 16:07:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Update:  I think I got it

```
var now = new Date('Jan 7, 2014 10:37:42 AM');
var UTC = new Date(now.toUTCString())
console.log(UTC) // returns Tue Jan 7 10:37:42 UTC+0530 2014
```

But not sure whether this is right or wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404247/datetime-to-javascript-date

Comment: Not duplicate of above...

Comment: Have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439630/how-do-you-create-a-javascript-date-object-with-a-set-timezone-without-using-a-s

They recommend some straightforward ways like setUTCHour() or Date.UTC(). But can you please clarify the question, it's not clear whether you want the input date as UTC or the output date as UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I parsed this string to date like
>
> ```
> var date = new Date("Jan 7, 2014 10:37:42 AM")
> ```
>
> This returns the dateTime in local format like `Tue Jan 07 2014
>   05:07:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
>
> How can I say that this date is already in UTC?

No, it does not return a dateTime in any format. It does return a [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) with the internal value of `1389091062000` milliseconds since epoch.

Only when you output it (e.g. when logging it to the console, or casting it to a string with `.toString`) it will be represented in your locale's timezone.

If you want to control the output, you would indeed use the [`toUTCString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString):

```
var date = new Date("Jan 7, 2014 10:37:42 AM")
date.toUTCString(); // "Tue, 07 Jan 2014 10:37:42 GMT"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following method for getting UTC.

```
var dat = new Date();
dat.toUTCString();
```

Comment: I already tried it, once again it is converting back to string.  I need to get it as UTC dateTime format

Comment: I got it, but I'm sure it is right.  I have edited +1 for the spark :)