# Date from javascript to C# is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime

I am trying to pass a datetime from C# to javascript.

I have converted my datetime at C# to FileTime (I am not sure, if this is the way to be done), and after that I passed this value to a ViewBag like this.

```
    ViewBag.minDate = minDate.ToFileTime();
```

Next I do this at javascript

```
    var date = new Date(Date.parse(<%=ViewBag.minDate%>));
```

Which becomes the following, but I get "*Invalid Date*"

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(130014720000000000)
```

Do you know why is that, and How I can fix it?

Comment: how are you getting timestamp value = `130014720000000000`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404247/datetime-to-javascript-date

Comment: @JimBlum refer above link

Comment: Have you tried the code in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ViewBag.minDate = minDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Yes, this is what I used :), but forgot to choose as best answer. That solved my problem. Just to learn, and nothing more, why we create a new date 1-1-1970? I know that was the first date at a UNIX , but why we do that? And thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: In javascript, "Date objects are based on a time value that is the number of milliseconds since 1 January, 1970 UTC." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
But in C# there is no such thing. To normalize, we need to subtract this date from C# date.

Comment: You are welcome. In stackoverflow, you learn things pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

pass the date like this,

```
ViewBag.minDate =minDate.ToString("o")
```

and in your view,

```
var date = new Date("<%=ViewBag.minDate %>")
```

Comment: Can you check the generated javascript in the browser? This should work.

Comment: I was wrong. The invalid date was produced by something else I had wrong. Thanks a lot. Just upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

or just:

```
ViewBag.SomeDate = DateTime.Now;
```

and then by using new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds):

```
var date = new Date(<%:ViewBag.SomeDate.Year%>, <%:ViewBag.SomeDate.Month%>, <%:ViewBag.SomeDate.Day%>, <%:ViewBag.SomeDate.Hour%>, <%:ViewBag.SomeDate.Minute%>, <%:ViewBag.SomeDate.Second%>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following code.

```
var newDate = new Date(parseInt(ViewBag.minDate.substr(6)));
                    var day = ("0" + newDate.getDate()).slice(-2);
                    var month = ("0" + (newDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
                    var date = newDate.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
```