# Return client specific date format to server MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

There is an **MVC 4** **Web Application** deployed on a server with specific date format (ex. US date format *02/02/2015*).

How can i display a date on the client machine by respecting his local date culture (ex. Uk format *02-02-2015*) so that when I retrive from the server the value 02/02/2015 on the client side it will be 02-02-2015?

I tried to use:

> date.toLocaleDateString()

but whatever format i choose for my client machine the output remains the same.

Or if it is possible, how can i get the clients system date to pass it to my controller without asking to choose a format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a situation like that, it would probably be best to send over the date in ticks.

Per [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2404271/1195056), you can take your `DateTime` object, convert it to UTC, and then convert it back to a date in the client.

```
modelDate = myDate.ToUniversalTime()
                  .Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
                  .TotalMilliseconds();
```

Then just pass it into a JavaScript variable on your page like so:

```
var date = new Date(@model.Date);
// Then assign it to whatever element with jQuery or JavaScript.
$('#dateBox').val(date);
```